# Textfield's cursor visible over footer while scrolling in iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, html, css, iphone-5

I have a page with header, footer and 2 textfields. when I click on textfield, virtual keypad open and textfield cursor start blinking. Now when I start scrolling my page, then textfield's cursor comes over footer.

I can only use HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, jQuery.

Comment: post some code , where you ended up?

Comment: So sorry for that, but i can not post the code. I have tried maximum z-index property on footer, so that footer comes on top but it didn't work. Please suggest something.!!

Comment: If you can't post your code, we likely can't help.